# What is the name of the story where a guy goes to an alien planet to test a disintegration gun?

Tags: story-identification

When I was in the 6th grade we read a book which was a collection of smaller books (or stories), which was perhaps a text book compilation. This book included The Jungle Book, but also had a few stories that I don't recall the name of.

In one of the stores a man travels to an alien planet with a disintegration gun, there he field tests the weapon on some hostile monkey-like creatures. Things go poorly, he gets injured, he shoots part of his ship with the **weapon**, leaving him stranded on the alien planet. At the end the people who hired him come looking for him and find him living on the land with a bow and arrow, and using the gun as a hammer.

Since the story continuously called the disintegration gun **"the weapon"** I expected it to be called that, but I couldn't find anything similar online.

Comment: It may help to know how long ago 6th grade was. 10 years, 20 years, 30 years?

Comment: From Jack's profile I deduce that it must have been 18-19 years ago

Comment: Can't resist quoting: "Well, what do you know? It disintegrated!"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[*The Gun Without a Bang*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71155) by [Robert Sheckley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley).

[From a very similar question:](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Science-Fiction-Books-2157/2008/1/completely-useless-weapon.htm)

> An astronaut lands on an alien world
> armed with an experimental weapon that
> disintegrates matter in a cone shape
> in front of it.  However, the weapon
> makes no noise or flash, nothing.  The
> alien planet is filled with aggressive
> creatures that attack him instantly.
>
> Flash forward, and the astronaut is
> picked up -- my friend couldn't recall
> if the astronaut was rescued from a
> mishap or lifted off the planet after
> a field test of weapon.  The landing
> party locate the astronaut using this
> fancy, high-tech weapon as a tool to
> hammer tent stakes, having fashioned
> "traditional" weapons to deal with the
> aggressive natives:  spears, knives,
> etc.  The astronaut explains that,
> although the gun functioned perfectly,
> it proved worthless as a psychological
> deterrent because it didn't make a
> boom or a nifty light show.  Although
> the gun was great at wounding or
> killing the animals and primitives, it
> did nothing to scare them off because
> they lacked the reasoning skills to
> equate the killing or wounding of
> their numbers with anything he (the
> astronaut) was doing to them.

You might be able to find a copy of it [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000I4NOWO) or [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BN9D36).

Having read it in 6th grade, you may have encountered it in a [Great Books Anthology](http://cgi.ebay.com/Junior-Great-Books-Series-7-Student-Anthology-/230587501411).