# Earth men land on planet with wolf/dog-like predators, use newly developed ray guns with unlimited range

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

Earth men land on a planet filled with wolf- or dog-like predators. They have newly developed ray guns and fight off the predators that attack them when they leave the ship. Upon returning to the ship they find the unlimited range of the ray guns has sliced up the ship during the battle and stranded them. Upon eventual rescue there is a lone survivor.

It is a mid-70's sci-fi short story from an anthology.

Comment: Similar to this question? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247213/short-story-about-a-man-stranded-on-a-strange-planet-testing-a-new-ray-gun-who-f  Everything fits, except it was a single man (Dixon) instead of a group.

Comment: https://schlock-value.com/2021/06/06/the-gun-without-a-bang/ mentions him accidentally shooting his own ship up.

Comment: "Sunlight? Inside a spaceship?
He sat up. At his feet lay the tail and one leg of the dog. Beyond it there was an interesting zigzag slashed through the side of the spaceship. It was about three inches wide and four feet long. Sunlight filtered through it.
Outside, four dogs were sitting on their haunches, peering in.
He had cut through his spaceship while killing the last dog.
**Then he saw other slashes in the ship. Where had they come from?
Oh, yes, when he was fighting his way back to the ship.** That last hundred yards. A few shots must have touched the spaceship."

Comment: If it was an anthology from the mid-70s it was probably either the Sheckley collection [*Store of Infinity*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?273800) or the Hoskins anthology [*Wondermakers 2*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55302).

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/what-is-the-name-of-the-story-where-a-guy-goes-to-an-alien-planet-to-test-a-disi

Answer (score 33):

Apart from the fact that the question specifies a group of men, this sounds very much like "[The Gun Without A Bang](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71155)" a short story by Robert Sheckley that deals with the adventures of just one man.

The man, Alfred Dixon, is a weapons expert who is testing a new form of disintegration pistol, referred to simply as "The Weapon", on a jungle planet. He is attacked by dog-like creatures, and although he is able to kill them, the weapon's silence means that the animals are not scared by the gun - when they are hit they simply disappear. Eventually he resorts to constructing a crude bow and arrow which is much more effective as the animals can see the dead and wounded.

Unfortunately the weapon has a big range, and in the course of the fighting he had inadvertantly damaged his ship:

> Oh, yes, when he was fighting his way back to the ship. That last
> hundred yards. A few shots must have touched the spaceship...
>
> Here were the severed control cables. That was where the radio had
> been. Over there he had managed to nick the oxygen and water tanks in
> a single burst, which was good shooting by anybody’s standards. And
> here — yes, he’d done it, all right A really clever hook shot had cut
> the fuel lines. And the fuel had all run out in obedience to the law
> of gravity and formed a pool around the ship and sunk into the ground.

He stays marooned on the planet until a rescue mission is sent, and picks him up.

It was originally published in Galaxy in June 1958, under the pseudonym  Finn O'Donnevan, and the text of the story is available [here](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v16n02_1958-06/page/n89/mode/2up?view=theater&q=Oh%20yes). From the [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71155) page you can see that it was indeed included in a few anthologies in the 1970s.

Comment: Huh.  A liquid fuel personal rocket.